Is the error in translation of Genesis 19:5 deliberate?
I'm curious about a mis-translation in Genesis 19, verse 5. The hebrew version is

ה  וַיִּקְרְאוּ אֶל-לוֹט וַיֹּאמְרוּ לוֹ, אַיֵּה הָאֲנָשִׁים
אֲשֶׁר-בָּאוּ אֵלֶיךָ הַלָּיְלָה; הוֹצִיאֵם אֵלֵינוּ, וְנֵדְעָה אֹתָם.
waYiq'r'û el-lôţ waYom'rû lô aYëh häánäshiym ásher-Bäû ëleykhä
haLäy'läh hôtziyëm ëlëynû w'nëd'äh otäm 
And they called Lot and said
to him, Where are the people who came to you tonight? Bring them
to us, and we will know them

In the Vulgate bible, this appears as

vocaveruntque Loth et dixerunt ei ubi sunt viri qui introierunt ad te
nocte educ illos huc ut cognoscamus eos
And they called Lot, and said unto him, Where are the men that
came in unto thee by night, bring them hither, that we may know them.

The two translations into English can be checked with Google translate. Note that the beautiful, androgynous angels who visited Lot are described as הָאֲנָשִׁים (people) in the hebrew text and as viri (men) in the Latin text.
Was this simply a mistake on Jerome's part, or was it part of the growing movement to turn Christians against homosexuality, by claiming that Sodom was destroyed because of its inhabitants' desire to have sex with the "men".

"part of the growing movement to turn Christians against homosexuality" — Are you saying this movement happened in the 4th century?

@RayButterworth Exactly. In 314 the Council of Ancyra excluded homosexuals from receiving the sacrament. St Basil in 375 and Gregory of Nyssa in 390 demanded of homosexuals a 15-year penitential of self-mortification while going without the sacrament. Then there's St Augustine (346-430).

הָאֲנָשִׁ֛ים haanasim is everywhere else (as well as Genesis 19:5) translated as 'men'. See Biblehub Interlinear and Strong 376. The sin is no less if the multitude forcibly wanted to know people, so I cannot see any support for your conjecture.

@NigelJ That's pretty convincing.

@LukeSawczak please don't leave answers in the Comments section - it sets a bad precedent for others. Thanks!

The Vulgate is a Latin version of the Holy Bible, and largely the result of the labors of St Jerome (Eusebius Sophronius Hieronymus), who was commissioned by Pope Damasus I in 382 A.D. (vulgate.org)
This was not a mistake on Jerome's part.
I will note that you are correct. Google Translate does translate it as "the people":

However, the Hebrew root word used of the visitors is אִישׁ (ish) which means man.
I will further note that Google Translate also shows the frequency of how the word appears in public documents:

One thing to note is that you should not use Google Translate as an accurate representaion of a word.
According to Brown-Driver-Briggs

אִישׁ2166 is classified as noun masculine man


According to Strong's Concordance:

ish: man
Original Word: אִישׁ
Part of Speech: Noun Masculine
Transliteration: ish
Phonetic Spelling: (eesh)
Definition: man


Since it is a continuation of the preceding narrative, note that in Genesis 18:3, Abraham refers to his visitors as Adonai (My Lord).
In fact, Genesis 18:9-15 records a conversation between Abraham and his three visitors. The pronouns used in this passage for the same three visitors are alternately seen as they, men, he, and YHWH.

If we look at the Englishman's Concordance you'll see the translation frequency in the NAS and INT as "men" is overwhelming:
hā·’ă·nā·šîm — 82 Occurrences

Genesis 14:24
HEB: הַנְּעָרִ֔ים וְחֵ֙לֶק֙ הָֽאֲנָשִׁ֔ים אֲשֶׁ֥ר הָלְכ֖וּ
NAS: and the share of the men who
INT: the young and the share of the men who went
Genesis 18:22
HEB: וַיִּפְנ֤וּ מִשָּׁם֙ הָֽאֲנָשִׁ֔ים וַיֵּלְכ֖וּ סְדֹ֑מָה
NAS: Then the men turned away from there
INT: turned there the men and went Sodom
Genesis 19:5
HEB: ל֔וֹ אַיֵּ֧ה הָאֲנָשִׁ֛ים אֲשֶׁר־ בָּ֥אוּ
NAS: to him, Where are the men who
INT: and said Where are the men who came
Genesis 19:10
HEB: וַיִּשְׁלְח֤וּ הָֽאֲנָשִׁים֙ אֶת־ יָדָ֔ם
NAS: But the men reached out their hands
INT: reached the men their hands and brought
Genesis 19:11
HEB: וְֽאֶת־ הָאֲנָשִׁ֞ים אֲשֶׁר־ פֶּ֣תַח
NAS: They struck the men who
INT: the men who the doorway
Genesis 19:12
HEB: וַיֹּאמְר֨וּ הָאֲנָשִׁ֜ים אֶל־ ל֗וֹט
NAS: Then the [two] men said to Lot,
INT: said the men to Lot
Genesis 19:16
HEB: וַֽיִּתְמַהְמָ֓הּ ׀ וַיַּחֲזִ֨קוּ הָאֲנָשִׁ֜ים בְּיָד֣וֹ וּבְיַד־
NAS: But he hesitated. So the men seized
INT: hesitated seized the men his hand and the hand
Genesis 20:8
HEB: בְּאָזְנֵיהֶ֑ם וַיִּֽירְא֥וּ הָאֲנָשִׁ֖ים מְאֹֽד׃
NAS: in their hearing; and the men were greatly
INT: their hearing frightened and the men were greatly
Genesis 34:7
HEB: כְּשָׁמְעָ֔ם וַיִּֽתְעַצְּבוּ֙ הָֽאֲנָשִׁ֔ים וַיִּ֥חַר לָהֶ֖ם
NAS: when they heard [it]; and the men were grieved,
INT: heard were grieved and the men angry were very
Genesis 34:21
HEB: הָאֲנָשִׁ֨ים הָאֵ֜לֶּה שְֽׁלֵמִ֧ים
NAS: These men are friendly
INT: men These are friendly
Genesis 34:22
HEB: יֵאֹ֨תוּ לָ֤נוּ הָאֲנָשִׁים֙ לָשֶׁ֣בֶת אִתָּ֔נוּ
NAS: on this [condition] will the men consent
INT: herein consent will the men to live for
Genesis 43:15
HEB: וַיִּקְח֤וּ הָֽאֲנָשִׁים֙ אֶת־ הַמִּנְחָ֣ה
NAS: So the men took this
INT: took the men present that
Genesis 43:17
HEB: הָאִ֛ישׁ אֶת־ הָאֲנָשִׁ֖ים בֵּ֥יתָה יוֹסֵֽף׃
INT: and brought the men the men house to Joseph's
Genesis 43:18
HEB: וַיִּֽירְא֣וּ הָֽאֲנָשִׁ֗ים כִּ֣י הֽוּבְאוּ֮
NAS: Now the men were afraid, because
INT: were afraid now the men because were brought
Genesis 43:24
HEB: הָאִ֛ישׁ אֶת־ הָאֲנָשִׁ֖ים בֵּ֣יתָה יוֹסֵ֑ף
NAS: brought the men into Joseph's
INT: brought the man the men house Joseph's
Genesis 43:33
HEB: כִּצְעִרָת֑וֹ וַיִּתְמְה֥וּ הָאֲנָשִׁ֖ים אִ֥ישׁ אֶל־
NAS: according to his youth, and the men looked
KJV: and the men marvelled one at another.
INT: to his youth looked and the men one about
Genesis 44:1
HEB: אֶת־ אַמְתְּחֹ֤ת הָֽאֲנָשִׁים֙ אֹ֔כֶל כַּאֲשֶׁ֥ר
NAS: Fill the men's sacks
KJV: and put every man's money
INT: Fill sacks the men's food as they
Genesis 44:4
HEB: רְדֹ֖ף אַחֲרֵ֣י הָֽאֲנָשִׁ֑ים וְהִשַּׂגְתָּם֙ וְאָמַרְתָּ֣
NAS: Up, follow the men; and when you overtake
INT: follow after the men overtake say

Feel free to see the rest of the verses:
Exodus 5:9,
Exodus 10:7,
Numbers 1:5,
Numbers 9:7,
Numbers 13:16,
Numbers 14:38,
Numbers 16:14,
Numbers 16:26,
Numbers 16:30,
Numbers 22:20,
Numbers 22:35,
Numbers 31:42,
Numbers 32:11,
Numbers 34:17,
Deuteronomy 19:17,
Deuteronomy 31:12,
Joshua 2:3,
Joshua 2:4,
Joshua 2:5,
Joshua 2:9,
Joshua 2:14,
Joshua 2:17,
Joshua 2:23,
Joshua 7:2,
Judges 8:18,
Judges 18:7,
Judges 18:17,
Judges 20:13,
1 Samuel 6:10,
1 Samuel 11:12,
1 Samuel 17:28,
1 Samuel 30:21,
2 Samuel 1:11,
2 Samuel 11:23,
2 Samuel 18:28,
1 Kings 21:13,
2 Kings 10:24,
2 Kings 18:27,
2 Kings 20:14,
2 Chronicles 2:17,
2 Chronicles 28:15,
Nehemiah 8:3,
Nehemiah 11:2,
Job 32:5,
Isaiah 36:12,
Isaiah 66:24,
Jeremiah 34:18,
Jeremiah 38:9,
Jeremiah 38:11,
Jeremiah 38:16,
Jeremiah 39:17,
Jeremiah 41:2,
Jeremiah 41:9,
Jeremiah 41:12,
Jeremiah 42:17,
Jeremiah 43:2,
Jeremiah 44:15,
Ezekiel 11:2,
Ezekiel 14:3,
Ezekiel 14:16,
Ezekiel 14:18,
Jonah 1:16,
Zephaniah 1:12


The Jewish Publication Society translates the previous verse and this verse as:

They had not yet lain down, when the townspeople, the men of Sodom, young and old—all the people to the last man—gathered about the house. And they shouted to Lot and said to him, “Where are the men who came to you tonight? Bring them out to us, that we may be intimate with them.”
(Gen19:4–5, JPS1985)


טֶרֶם֮ יִשְׁכָּבוּ֒ וְאַנְשֵׁ֨י הָעִ֜יר ‬אַנְשֵׁ֤י סְדֹם֙‬ נָסַ֣בּוּ עַל־הַבַּ֔יִת מִנַּ֖עַר וְעַד־זָקֵ֑ן כָּל־הָעָ֖ם מִקָּצֶֽה׃ וַיִּקְרְא֤וּ אֶל־לֹוט֙ וַיֹּ֣אמְרוּ לֹ֔ו אַיֵּ֧ה הָאֲנָשִׁ֛ים‬ אֲשֶׁר־בָּ֥אוּ אֵלֶ֖יךָ הַלָּ֑יְלָה הֹוצִיאֵ֣ם אֵלֵ֔ינוּ וְנֵדְעָ֖ה אֹתָֽם׃
(Gen. 19:4-5, BHS2003)

Translating הָאֲנָשִׁ֛ים
(noun masculine plural absolute with the article) depends on the context.
Masculine singular אִישׁ means man.
Feminine singular אִשָּׁה means woman.
Masculine plural אֲנָשִׁ֔ים can mean men or people.
Feminine plural נָשִׁ֖ים means women.
The nouns/adjectives translated young נַ֫עַר and old זָקֵן are masculine singular and both have feminine forms not used here.  Thus, the singular emphasizes men.
עַם (used in v4) is a word meaning people.
The way angels are described they apparently looked like men and had men's names (Gabriel Dan 8:16; Michael Jude 9).  Thus, the men of Sodom would think they were men.

The LORD appeared to him by the terebinths of Mamre; he was sitting at the entrance of the tent as the day grew hot. 2Looking up, he saw three men standing near him. As soon as he saw them, he ran from the entrance of the tent to greet them and, bowing to the ground,
(Gen. 18:1–2, JPS1985)

Thus, the difference in the translations is not caused by mistranslation, but by the difference in how הָאֲנָשִׁ֛ים can be translated.
P.S. As Dieter noted the Septuagint (LXX) translated הָאֲנָשִׁ֛ים as ἄνδρες, which definitely means male humans as opposed to ἄνθρωπος.

καὶ ἐξεκαλοῦντο τὸν Λωτ καὶ ἔλεγον πρὸς αὐτόν Ποῦ εἰσιν οἱ ἄνδρες οἱ εἰσελθόντες πρὸς σὲ τὴν νύκτα; ἐξάγαγε αὐτοὺς πρὸς ἡμᾶς, ἵνα συγγενώμεθα αὐτοῖς.
(Ge 19:5, LXX)

Also, your question may be based on knowing modern Hebrew, which unlike Biblical Hebrew tends to use גבר for a man as opposed to איש to make it less ambiguous.

I'd also note that, even in English, "men" and "man" can mean "people" and "person." It's far less common now, to the point some would call it archaic. But it was very common in the past. So translating a word that can mean men or people would make "men" more common.

@ trlkly True.  Even modern Hebrew tends to use גבר for a man as opposed to איש to make it less ambiguous.

The translation of the Tanakh (aka "The Old Testament") from Hebrew into Greek is called the Septuagint. It is commonly dated to the 3rd century BC during the reign of Ptolemy II Philadelphus of Egypt (285-246 BC) in the city of Alexandria. It's estimated that a million Greek-speaking Jews lived in Alexandria at that time and that this Greek translation made the Tanakh accessible to them.
The Septuagint has immense historical and hermeneutical value since it represents "a snapshot in time" of the contemporary interpretations of Jewish scholars under the auspices of the Sanhedrin in Jerusalem.
For Genesis 19:5, the translators of the Septuagint chose the Greek word ἀνδρός (andros). Looking up this word in Strong's Greek 435, we see that the word generally means "man," and in the BDAG (p75), it is defined primarily as "an adult human male," including a husband in contrast with an adult human female.
Also note that homosexuality as indicated in Genesis 19 was widespread in Greek and Roman culture. In fact, pederasty was customary, idealized, and institutionalized in Greek and Roman culture for most men and pubescent boys [at least as far the upper classes--thank you, FelixLXX].
Also significant to Genesis 19 is that archaeological work currently being done at Tall el-Hammam demonstrated that the architecture there was in the style of Minoan architecture! Due to it's apparent confirmation of the Genesis narrative, this site is considered highly controversial. Here's more information about the possible location of the biblical Sodom:
https://www.biblicalarchaeology.org/daily/biblical-sites-places/biblical-archaeology-sites/where-is-sodom/
https://religionnews.com/2022/04/20/after-scientists-debate-meltdown-of-biblical-sodom/

Kenneth Dover's theory that pederasty was customary and idealised isn't universally supported and that might be off-topic for the OP, but sources should be cited for that. We can only really see into the ideals of a tiny subsection of a small, literate elite - and there might be a recurring social process, like in present-day Britain and America and Canada, where large contingents of society become quite disgruntled with what the elite put in the libraries and paint on the pots.

Yes, great point, FelixLXX! Surviving manuscripts are typically from the literate elite, who weren't particularly concerned with the common/rural people. The same is true for the history of Christianity with the exception of numerous pietistic movements just under the surface and often persecuted. "But many who are first will be last, and the last first."

We don't don't know enough about St Jerome's sources to answer this
St Jerome natively spoke Illyrian with Koine Greek and Latin being secondary languages and Hebrew being a language he only started to study much later in life.  There were already many Latin translations of the Bible by the time the Vulgate translation was written; however, they were all translated from the Septuagint (LXX) Greek Bible which was criticized as being too literal of a translation which lead to many misinterpretations of scripture.
St. Jerome knew of this criticism, but he did not know Hybrew well enough to translate the Bible directly from Hebrew to Latin.  Instead he chose to focus his work on using the Symmachus as his primary source: a different Koine Greek translation of the Bible that had a reputation for translating the meaning of the Hebrew expressions in ways that were more understandable to Greeks as opposed to the more literal translations done to date. It is also believed that St. Jerome used an additional Hebrew source, but we do not know what that source was, or what that version said.  Furthermore we no longer have any complete version of the Symmachus, most of what remains of this translation only exists in St. Jerome's notes.  So, we often don't know when it is St Jerome or Symmachus who add any given interpretation, or if it was just an inclusion from an already modified source.  What we do know is that other Greek translations already made the male definitive translation before Symmachus wrote his translation; so, it's very possible that either Symmachus or St Jerome were influenced by this tradition after it was already started.
While it is believed that St. Jerome also had a Hebrew source, we do not know what that source was, and if he was relying on it when translating this passage or if he were simply translating the Greek Symmachus directly into Latin as large parts of his translation appear to be.

